# Replacing pattern in PHP

Tags: php, regex

I have pattern in string to be replaced with something else.

e.g.

```
$str = '{1} Foo Bar {4}';
```

I want the above string to be converted like:

```
$str = arg(0). 'Foo Bar'.arg(4)
```

Comment: Have you tried anything so far ?

Comment: Don't get it : you only want to remove spaces around "Foo Bar" ?

Comment: No, i want to replace the pattern {number} to arg(number).
e.g. {2} should be arg(2), where arg() is function.

Comment: Please, Get more details

Answer (score 2):

In such cases it's best to use [`preg_replace_callback()`](http://php.net/preg_replace_callback). It's unclear what `arg(4)` is, variable or real function call.

Only if you can constrain the matched values, you may use [`preg_replace`](http://php.net/preg_replace) with `/e` like that:

```
 $text = preg_replace('~ [{] (\d+) [}] ~xie', 'arg($1)', $text);
```

That would invoke `arg($decimal)` for each occurence of `{n}`. Workable if you only match decimals like in your example.

Comment: Thanks, Its really awesome solution.
This is exactly i was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Go through this functions

[**str_replace**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)

[**preg_replace**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)

```
for(i=0;i<n;i++){

$str = str_replace("{i}", arg(i), $str);
}
```